# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DropdownModule'

Tags: node.js, angular, primeng

I'm trying to use p-table in a component. Every time I import the TableModule from app.module.ts, I get the following error:

```
compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DropdownModule'
at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
at compiler.js:10589
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:10558)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:10493)
at compiler.js:10580
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:10558)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:10493)
at compiler.js:10580
```

I'm not importing nor using dropdown module anywhere. I dont understand how dropdown is related to Tablemodule.

I tried importing DropdownModule with :

```
import {DropdownModule} from "primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown";
```

but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your p-table?

Comment: even if i write hello world without using the tag p-table, it gives this error

Comment: Then maybe you should change the description of the question. Without looking at the code I doubt anyone would be able to solve the issue

Comment: What version of `@angular/cdk` and `primeng` do you have?

Comment: I get the same error after upgrading to PrimeNG v7. v6^ is fine. Are you using Angular 7?